# Does normalizing dependent and independent variables 0 and 1 vanish the importances of independent variables?

Tags: machine-learning, multiple-regression, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics

I am wondering if the weights, importance, of independent variables vanish if independent and dependent variables are normalized between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

The weights and importance will change. The question is whether it is desired or not. The answer depends - among others - on the architecture used:

- If you use any penalization of weights such as L1 or L2, then the normalization is desired as the independent variables are treated fairly. This holds for MLP, polynomial, linear and logistic regression.
- If you use quantities that are considering are used as a reasonable distance (e.g. x and y coordinates), then all kernel based methods shall benefit from not normalizing the data. This class embraces kernelized SVM and RBF.